# entries in toc separated by same distances

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I am using [Easy Thesis](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis) template to write my thesis.

I want to add a 'chapter like page' to write a list of conferences and posters I did during studies.

So below I explain what I did to create a page in that template.

1. I define a new command in `Thesis.cls` file. The code is:

   ```
   \newcommand\scientificcontribution[1]{
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \begin{flushleft}{\huge{\bf{List of Scientific Contribution}} \par}\end{flushleft}
   {\normalsize #1} }
   ```
2. I create a `.tex` file with file name `listofsciencecontribution.tex`. And on top of this file I added the code below:

   ```
   \clearpage
   \addtotoc{LIST OF SCIENTIFIC CONTRIBUTION}
   \setstretch{1.3}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \scientificcontribution{
   \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em} }
   }
   ```
3. Lastly I write the calling command (`\input{listofpublication`) in the `Thesis.tex` file after the bibliography session.

The compiling goes with no problem. But what I notice is the separation distance between entry REFERENCES and LIST OF SCIENTIFIC CONTRIBUTION in the table of contents are shorter.

What should I do to make the entries in the same separation distance.

Finally, I can see the header following title "REFERENCE" in the List Of Scientific Contributions. Instead that header should be "LIST OF SCIENTIFIC CONTRIBUTIONS"

How I can make this happen?

Appreciate your help

The minimal order in my `Thesis.tex` file

The `Thesis.tex` file has many sections in order like,

```
\frontmatter
Table of Contents
List of Figure
List of Table
List of Abbreviations
List of Symbols


\mainmatter
include chapter1.tex
include chapter2.tex
include chapter3.tex

\backmatter
Biblography
```

[here I want to inlcude the page "List of Scientific Contributions]

```
\appendix
```

I wanted to insert a newpage with title "**List of Scientific contribution**" in between `\backmatter` and `\appendix`. When I try this I find the header giving me some problem.

For every other chapters I get the header follow as the chapter title.
But for the page "**List of Scientific contribution**", I get the header to be "*REFERENCES*".

I have given example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265685/header-is-not-synchronize-with-title-page?noredirect=1#comment636495_265685)

Comment: Unrelated comment: Neither `\huge` nor `\bf` are commands that take an argument (and `\bf` has been deprecated for about 20 years) so you should have `\huge\bfseries List of Scientific Contributions`, without the brace pairs. As environments form a group I don't think the braces before `\huge` and after `\par` are necessary either.

Comment: try with `\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1cm} }
\addtotoc{LIST OF SCIENTIFIC CONTRIBUTION}` 1cm just for example

Comment: All toc entries are lowercase so why do you use uppercase?

Comment: Dear @touhami Thanks for your help. It works fine for me. Well the "LIST OF SCIENTIFIC CONTRIBUTION" in capital because my university requires this.

Comment: By the way, I notice the header of the following page after List Of Scientific page, is not "List Of Scientific page"... is there anything I missed? Can anyone give suggest?

Comment: replace `\pagestyle{fancy}` with `\lhead{\emph{List Of Scientific page}}` in top of your `listofsciencecontribution.tex`

Comment: Dear @touhami, this gives the header from the page "List Of Scientific page" up to including Appendix pages too... For your information I added this page after the "Reference" section in the Thesis.tex file.

Comment: following link you provide appendix are befor and references are last thing no? please add a minimale example of your code i.e. how do yo strecture your thesis.tex

Comment: I have added the order of the list in the Thesis.tex for your view.