# header is not synchronize with title page

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I am using [Easy Thesis](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis) to write my thesis. I need to add a page called "**List of Scientific Contribution**" and I added successfully as described in  [my earlier post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264500/entries-in-toc-sparated-with-same-disstances) after the **Reference** page.

But now I have a problem in the header of the page that I added and in the following pages.

I have shown below the added new page below (page 7). If you see the header is emerged as *REFERENCES* which supposed **NOT** be there since this the starting page.

[image]

The following page (page 8) from above  should have header *List of Scientific Contribution* but it appears to be  *REFERENCES*. I shown the page (page 8) below.

[image]

Final issue is, this affects the appendix pages also. In the appendix page (page 11) the header supposed appear as *Appendix A* for example. But it appears as shown in the below picture.

[image]

Can I get some help to resolve this problem?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please try, if this is the same with `report` and post a minimal example here.

Comment: The last image: The header is correct. You are missing your title.

Comment: Possibly `\markboth{List of Publications}{List of Publications}`. But as it stands, the question cannot be answered.